# Linking to copyrighted material on YouTube?

Tags: discussion

In a current question ([here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/nineties-sitcom-about-small-software-company/1404#comment2093_1404)), the original poster commented on my answer that the pilot episode of the TV show in question is on YouTube. Is it appropriate to link to this content?

While I think erring on the side of caution and not doing so is the right thing to do, part of me believes it will improve the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copyright as you are no-doubt aware is an enormously complex area - made worse by the interconnected nature of the web, issues of what comprises 'fair use' of copyrighted material.

The clearest statement from Stack-Exchange that I have seen is in this post https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/879/should-we-permit-linking-to-illegal-stuff/880#880

This is from Jeff Atwood (co-founder and an employee at the time), and clearly states that linking to egregiously illegal content should be discouraged.

I have not seen the content, so cannot judge for myself, but if you think it is clearly in breach of copyright, then I would say that it would be best not to include it.  If you think it falls into '[fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)' then a link should be ok.

Comment: Another interesting discussion is here: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1349/should-we-allow-links-to-sources-of-a-questionable-legal-status

Comment: I'm going with 'no,' because it makes more sense to leave it and move on rather than dance around the 'fair use' issue. Thanks for the input!