# Are links to clickpay.to allowed per SE's Terms of Service?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19233/what-does-this-scene-with-meg-turning-her-rooms-lamp-on-and-off-refer-to) contains a link to the site `clickplay.to`, on which you can stream whole series in HD (in the case of this question, Family Guy).

Coming from a country with an incredibly sucky copyright law, to me this sounds a bit too good to be true.

I know that there are legal services like Hulu that stream TV content, however those are usually not accessible in my country (Germany) and mostly restricted to the US. So the following facts about this site make me suspicious:

- It does not seem to have any country restriction at all.
- The terms of use and privacy policy links on the site don't seem to work.
- Looks like they are associated to or, more likely, might be imitating `clickplay.ph`, a similar (but payment based and not quite as fishy) site for movies on demand. (I have no idea how legal this is either, though.)

What makes me most suspicious: If this was a legal service, I would've probably heard of it by now, because I have been waiting for a payed service with this wide range of content and this quality in my country for a long time.

SE's term of state that

> Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that [...] c) infringes any intellectual property right of another or the privacy or publicity rights of another

While it may not be totally clear if this includes links to such content, [the general consensus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145356/link-pointing-to-illegal-content) seems to be that linking to it is not allowed.

- Does `clickpay.to` infringe copyright, or is it a legal service?
- and related: Are links to this service allowed in our questions and answers?

Answer (score 2):

Copyright and 'fair use' of material is a grey area, and becomes even more difficult when it relates to linking - however I don't want to rehash the discussions from previous posts relating to this:

[Post about linking to material on YouTube](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/linking-to-copyrighted-material-on-youtube)

[Post about use of copyright material](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/405/40)

Most of the video material linked to on this site is hosted by YouTube, which has huge numbers of short clips of TV shows and Movies.  However YouTube is clearly a legitimate site, with a clear policy for taking down material for which the 'fair use' is challenged by the copyright holder.

So to contrast with this with clickpay.to.  It seems very likely to me, unless someone can specifically point to evidence to the contrary, that a site hosting full episodes of current TV shows for free is infringing copyright.  [Linking to egregiously illegal content is not allowed](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/880), so I will be removing this link from the post.

Comment: `It seems very unlikely to me [..] that a site hosting full episodes [..] is very likely to be infringing copyright.` I think you got lost somewhere in this sentence. \*g\* I understand the intention though and agree.

Comment: The main point of my question was that it's quite possible that this is a known legal service which I am just ignorant of. If that it's not the case, I agree that it should be treated as illegal until proven otherwise, especially as all the indicators point to it being shady.

Comment: @atticae - Ahahaha, yes, I did get lost somewhere in that sentence, I'll edit it!